# Why are there such things as 'time adverbs'?

Tags: grammar

Words like yesterday, today, and tomorrow are defined as adverbs. However, an adverb is a word modifying an adjective or verb (or another adverb). Words such as yesterday do not seem to modify anything of the sorts.

In reading a book about grammar, a sentence is given as an example of the use of adverbs:

"Yesterday the quite relieved soldier very quickly ran out of the woods when he saw his comrade frantically waving to him".

I'll come back to the word 'yesterday'. Apart from that, the book identifies 'quite', 'very', 'quickly' and 'frantically' as adverbs. Let's make a table of the adverb and the thing it modifies:

```
Adverb          Modifies
___________________________________
Quite       |   Relieved(adjective)
Very        |   Quickly(adverb)
Quickly     |   Ran(verb)
Frantically |   Waving (verb)
```

Ok, so back to yesterday (how poetic). Yesterday doesn't actually seem to modify anything. Apparently, it modifies the verb ran, and this is coming from the book. However, we need to note two things here:

1. Extending the present logic, if it 'modifies' the verb ran, surely it modifies everything else since everything took place yesterday. If it modifies the action of running, then *surely* it modifies the other action: waving. Perhaps it also modifies other adverbs, and adjectives, too.
2. What does it mean to modify? Surely the way that an action is executed transcends time. I could run in an identical way to how I ran yesterday or will run tomorrow. Yet the action is supposedly modified depending upon the time it's executed. Well, extending this logic, why not place? And the agent executing the action?

So it doesn't seem correct to say that time modifies adverbs. If anything, it seems more related to pronouns, since a pronoun is a word that stands in for someone else, in the same way 'yesterday' is a word that stands in for everything that happened within the span of 24 hours within the boundaries of our planet earth. So yeah, I don't really see the logic.

Comment: "However, an adverb is a word modifying an adjective or verb (or another adverb)." No. Adverbs are not defined that way. Adverbs can also modify verb phrases, sentences, pretty much anything which not already modified by adjectives (like nouns in English). This more or less already answers your question, because most syntacticians would probably reject your definition as too strict and see the mentioned cases of such time adverbs modifying a full sentence as perfectly natural and within the scope of what you would expect of an adverb.

Comment: Admittedly, this "pretty much anything" makes the notion of an "adverb" a rather vague one, potentially turning this word class to a kind of "garbage category" for anything which doesn't really match any of the other word classes, as long as it serves as a modifier in one or the other way. However, I wouldn't know where else to locate such words, and a category of words which generally modify verbs, verb phrases, sentence or similar constituents seems justified to me.

Comment: Your definition of pronoun in your last paragraph is too wide. According to it, "chair" would be a pronoun, because it stands for all chairs in the world. More to the point,a pronoun is a word that stands **for another word**, which is something that "yesterday" doesn't usually (and perhaps ever) do.

Comment: @LuísHenrique  Perhaps what the OP had in mind was _deictic_, rather than pronoun/pro-form.

Comment: @lemontree Not really, it just means that when it comes to adverbs, what they can modify is not a great diagnostic - that's all.

Comment: @LuísHenrique Not really, pronouns "stand in" for phrases (or other types of phrasal category), not words. *Yesterday* can be seen to be doing exactly that where *yesterday* may be seen to 'stand in' for a temporal adjunct (such as *Sunday*), but where, as is often the case with pronouns, the referent of the word is understood deictically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying that temporal expressions modify verbs is characteristic of the traditional grammar, adapted from the work of the Greeks and Romans, which has dominated English pedagogy since the 18th century.

One of the hallmarks of traditional grammar is a "dependency" approach which grounds itself in part-of-speech and tends to describe syntax as chains of word-to-word links. In that context the most convenient word in a sentence to attach a temporal expression to is the verb.

Contemporary grammar is oriented more toward grouping words into chunks which can move around together called "constituents"; and contemporary constituency grammarians will say that what temporal expressions modify is not the verb but either the "VP" (or "predicate"), the group of words headed by the verb, or the entire clause.

But it's often difficult to pin down just what, if anything, a temporal "modifies" (and the grammarians I have read mostly acknowledge that difficulty). I myself am currently playing around with a dramatistic analysis (based on the work of Kenneth Burke) which categorizes the gnarlier temporals and locatives as "scenic" components of the clause; but so far that approach has its own difficulties.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing category (part of speech) and function (subject, object, modifier, etc.).

Traditional grammar analyses items like "yesterday", "today" "tomorrow" etc, as nouns in, for example, "Today is the first day of my exams" but adverbs in, for example, "They arrived yesterday".

Modern grammars take them to be simply pronouns. They can’t be nouns because of their inability to take determiners, and they can’t be adverbs either for two reasons: consider “Their behaviour yesterday was unacceptable”, where “yesterday” is modifying the noun “behaviour”, which makes it unlike an adverb. And unlike adverbs, they have genitive forms, “today’s”, “yesterday’s” etc.

They have a number of functions, for example modifier (adjunct) as in “They arrive today”, and subject as in “Today is my birthday”. As adjuncts, they modify verb phrases.

Comment: What traditional grammar analyses "yesterday" etc. as a noun? Can you source your statement?

Comment: @jknappen The Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries for starters! Check out these [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/today), [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/today)

Comment: Strange analysis, IMO, because of the "verb second" rule also active in the German language. Can you really say "the today" or "a today"?

Comment: @jknappen As I said, one of the reasons that items like "today", "yesterday" etc. can't be nouns is that they don't take determiners. When used in examples like "Today is Thursday", the claim is that they are pronouns, not nouns.

Comment: Your example with "yesterday" modifying "behavior" is interesting, but unfortunately pronouns don't modify nouns.  And taking "adverb" to mean "modifier of something other than a noun", since you say they modify verb phrases, they must be adverbs.  Maybe they're PPs.

Comment: @Greg Lee - you almost have it.  A pronoun preceded by a preposition is a PP, which can function as an adverbial.  Now suppose the pronoun has a quality which disambiguates it from normal subjects and objects -- then the basic preposition ('at' or 'on') can be elided and we are left with a bare pronoun that functions as an adverbial -- thus we call it an adverb.

Comment: @Greg Lee It's much simpler than what aml is saying. It has nothing to do with PPs or adverbs. We're talking here about deictic pronouns in adjunct function. In "Their behaviour yesterday", we have a pronoun modifying a noun, and in "They arrived yesterday", "yesterday" is an adjunct of temporal location realised by an NP with a deictic pronoun as head.

Comment: I also think it's simpler than what @amI is saying.  The time and place adverbs under discussion are PPs.  There is no more reason for a PP to contain a preposition than there is for a NP to contain a noun.  So there is no P in "yesterday" to get rid of.  Now, as for BillJ's idea that these words are pronouns, I was trying to make clear that real pronouns (you know, "he, she, it ...") are not modifiers of anything.  Try some examples. *"He-Billj it-proposed that it-something strange."  I was talking about real pronouns, not Billj pronouns.

Comment: @GregLee We only have upstairs phrases, people like BillJ and me. Your downstairs phrases are our syntactic functions. So we *do* require a P in a PP and *nearly* always an N in an NP ...

Comment: @Araucaria, You only have upstairs phrases? I don't understand what that means.  Are you saying that verbs requiring PP arguments always require a P within that argument?  I can't think of any verbs like that.  Is there any evidence for the existence of a category PP that requires a P inside it?

Comment: @GregLee Indeed if they accept arguments that don't have a P within them, by definition they don't require PP arguments, but can accept other types of argument instead.

Comment: @Araucaria, If there is no empirical content to what you are saying here, why should anyone care?  I asked you for evidence, but evidently you have none.

Comment: @GregLee What kind of evidence do you have for the existence of a verb that must take PP complements but can take a complement without a P?

Comment: @Araucaria, You've just explained to me that there can be no such evidence.  It's not a factual matter -- it concerns only some definitions you made up.  So your question cannot be sincere.

Comment: @GregLee I was just sneaking out of your 'empirical evidence' trap, which, as you say, is neither here nor there in the context that because of the definition that, for example, CamGEL uses for phrases (althought thee are empirical reasons to adopt such an analysis. However, because my 'upstairs v downstairs' seemed to confuse you, I thought [*THIS POST* might be useful](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292397/what-part-of-speech-is-talking-in-the-following-sentence/292623#292623). However, I seem to have got my ups and downs upside down! Your upstairs is my syntactic functions ...

Comment: @GregLee And your downstairs is my phrasal category. (Where 'my' means that used by the grammars that people like BillJ and I, for example, subscribe to).

Comment: @Araucaria, I haven't really done a thorough investigation, but off-hand, I have not been able to think of any verb that takes PP complements with a preposition that does not also take a prepositionless complement in its place.  Not even one.  "He put the book there/on the table."  But why discuss facts?  They've become irrelevant for you -- you'll just make up some new category name for "there" in each such case.  You can always do that.  I can think of some other tests for syntactic category, but why even mention them?

Comment: @GregLee But *there* is well-known to fulfil nearly every syntactic test for prepositionhood going - which is why Jespersen, Emonds, Pullum, Huddlestion etc, etc, regard it as a preposition ... In any case it is rare for a verb that takes PP locative adjuncts to only take PP ones. We could, for example, have an NP complement there: "He put the book some place". In that case, there is no motivated reason to say "some place" is a PP, unless we confuse 'locative adjunct' with PP, imo.

Comment: @Araucaria, When you create a category "locative adjunct" for the purpose of adhering to your definition of PP as always containing a P, you're doing just as I said you would in my previous comment.  It's a game of definitions, and facts of language are no longer relevant.  I'm just not interested.

Comment: @GregLee "Locative Adjuntc" is a grammatical relation. It's not a phrasal category.

Answer (score 1):

James McCawley describes time and place adverbs as logical predicates of events or conditions which are grammatically expressed as sentences.  He gives some evidence that such adverbs can either modify the sentences that they predicate something of or, through a transformation he calls Raising, they can come to modify the V-bar constituents of those sentences.  This is my best recollection of the treatment in his book *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.

Haj Ross has observed that multiple time or place adverbs can be, or perhaps must be, organized so as to describe the time or place of an event with increasing specificity or increasing generality.  For instance "I eat meals in Honolulu in my cottage near the back in my kitchen at a table".  Other adverbs don't work this way.  I think he called such groups of related adverbs "trajectories".  (I don't know whether Haj has written this down.)

In answer to your question about modification, I'd say that is a grammatical idea about constituent structure, so it is not the sort of thing that has a meaning.  When a constituent of a certain category is part of a larger constituent of that same category, this is a modification structure, the smaller constituent is what is modified, and the modifier is what is outside the smaller constituent but within the larger one.  This roughly follows McCawley's treatment.

For instance, "yesterday" is a sentence modifier in the structure

```
[S yesterday [S I ate]]
```

"cautiously" is a V-bar modifier in

```
I [V-bar cautiously [V-bar ate my fish]]
```

and "completely" is a V modifier in

```
I [V completely [V ate]] my fish
```

Comment: Where can I read up on things like 'raising' and V-bar constituents, the terms seem alien to me. Thanks. Edit: To clarify, I know I could read his book, but I mean, is there a subject that these things fall under, so I could look them up on something like wikipedia?

Comment: The subject is "syntax".  Wikipedia has lots of good short articles.  Some of McCawley's book is available on line using Google.  Here, for example: https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA679&lpg=PA679&dq=mccawley+phenomena+adverbs&source=bl&ots=uOjE4N4vVj&sig=tP59WTkYNCP1KDbTB6u9fSWBGEE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgh6jDx6vQAhVHHGMKHbglA9wQ6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=mccawley%20phenomena%20adverbs&f=false

Comment: @JimJam, "V-bar" is a phrase whose head is a V.  Roughly synonymous are "verb phrase", "VP", "predicate" (the part of a sentence not the subject). "Raising" here refers to a generalized version of a rule that moves the subject of a subordinate sentence up to become subject (or object) of a superordinate sentence -- as when the subject "there" of the lower S in "It seemed that there was an explosion" becomes the subject of "seemed" in "There seemed to be an explosion."

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, these temporal words are [pro]nouns.  They are also called adverbs because any adverbial phrase that can be expressed in one word is called an adverb.  We know they are adverbial (we assume an elided preposition such as 'at') because they are temporal.

In your sentence, 'yesterday' modifies 'ran ...'.  The main verb is the only word that it needs to be associated with.  The other verbs are associated with it only indirectly (by nesting).  For example, if you change 'when' to 'after', then the waving may not have occurred yesterday.

Comment: This depends on the definition of "adverb" and "pronoun". See this answer: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/a-list-of-parts-of-speech/12994#12994

Comment: Well, "yesterday" may be a noun; there is a day called "yesterday". But this is not true of other "temporal adverbs", such as "now" or "later".

Comment: @LuísHenrique While *yesterday* can be a noun, it still has various peculiar properties you would not expect of a common noun. Yes, it can be the subject or object of a clause or PPobj, but it resists articles and most other determiners just as a personal pronoun or a person’s name does. Many run-of-the-bill noun phrases will not abide having their noun replaced by it, and the temporal deixis built into the word seems to block moving its point of view. It mislikes inflection, despite how ***all our yesterdays** have lighted fools the way to dusty death.* Cf. *yesteryear* and OE *giestran dæg*.

Comment: @tchrist - Good points. I don't think that "yesterday" is a noun that can be used as an adverb. Rather it seems to me an "adverb" (whatever an "adverb" may be) that can be used as a noun in certain, quite limited, contexts. This is even more true of most other "temporalisers".

Comment: It is a **bold** thing to say they are nouns/pronouns. Certainly you can trace many adverbs back to nouns (typically some time unit/period in a locational case), quite a lot of them are very far from this origin. And while English permits to force them into a noun (just as much as you can force a pronoun to become a verb as in "I thou thee, thou traitor"), it certainly is not cross-linguistically valid. With the pronoun - I would very much discourage from this word due to possible confusion and rather resort to Jakobson's "*shifter*".

Comment: We're talking here about deictic pronouns in adjunct function. In "Their behaviour yesterday", we have a pronoun modifying a noun, and in "They arrived yesterday", "yesterday" is an adjunct of temporal location realised by an NP with a deictic pronoun as head.

Comment: " They are also called adverbs because any adverbial phrase that can be expressed in one word is called an adverb. " <--- That is just confusing the difference between parts of speech and grammatical relations.

Comment: I am trying to explain the confusion that grammarians have created with the term adverb.  The only POS that deserves to be called 'adverb' is adjective+'ly'.  All other "adverbs" are either intensifiers (ad-words) or nouns with elided prepositions.  I know this sounds crazy: 'soon' = '[at] soon'; but that is why "the meeting is soon" means that the meeting is at an approaching time rather than the meeting IS an approaching time.

Comment: English allows sentences like "The next day, he went to the zoo."  The adverbial phrase is clearly an NP, with nary an adverb.  It is congruent to the PP 'on the next day', and it works (with the preposition elided) because 'day' is temporal.

Answer (score 0):

As StoneyB says, the idea that adverbs "modify" verbs is characteristic of traditional grammar. More generally, traditional grammar tends to get syntax and semantics entangled, which doesn't really help in understanding what words in general - and adverbs in particular - do in the sentences they take part in.

A better, and more modern, approach would be to investigate the syntatic behaviour of words:

"Yesterday", as many other "adverbs", behaves very differently from, for intance, "quite":

> Yesterday the relieved soldier ran out of the woods.

It is easy to see that "yesterday" can be placed in several different places within this sentence:

> Yesterday the relieved soldier ran out of the woods.
>
> The relieved soldier, yesterday, ran out of the woods.
>
> The relieved soldier ran, yesterday, out of the woods.
>
> The relieved soldier ran out of the woods yesterday.

While these sentences may imply different emphases, they are basically synonymous.

"Quite", on the other hand, seems firmly attached to the adjective it "modifies":

> The quite relieved soldier ran out of the woods.
>
> *The relieved soldier, quite, ran out of the woods.
>
> *The relieved soldier ran, quite, out of the woods.
>
> *The relieved soldier ran out of the woods quite.

And while we perhaps can say

> The relieved soldier quite ran out of the woods.
>
> The relieved soldier ran quite out of the woods.

it seems obvious to me that these sentences are not synonymous, either with the original sentence, or with each other.

On the other hand, adverbs like "luckily", "hopefully", "understandably", behave in a similar way to "yesterday":

> Luckily the relieved soldier ran out of the woods.
>
> The relieved soldier, luckily, ran out of the woods.
>
> The relieved soldier ran, luckily, out of the woods.
>
> The relieved soldier ran out of the woods, luckily.

Though, as in the last sentence of the example, they seem to have peculiar issues with commas - and with verbal tenses, as shown below:

> Yesterday the relieved soldier ran out of the woods.
>
> *Yesterday the relieved soldier will run out of the woods.
>
> *Hopefully the relieved soldier ran out of the woods.
>
> Hopefully the relieved soldier will run out of the woods.

Anyway, it would be possibly convenient to group these "adverbs" for their mobility, ie, for their syntactic behaviour, rather, or at least before, the conventional semi-semantic classification as "temporal", "modal", etc., adverbs. This would avoid the quite awkard grouping of "gladly" and "quickly" as similar words, which they most probably are not.

Comment: We should distinguish between intensifiers ('quite', 'very', ...) and adverbials.  'Adverb' should mean: an adverbial phrase which is expressed (by elision or morphology) using a single word.  'Sunday' can be used as an adverb, but it is really a deictic noun in the phrase 'on Sunday'.  'Quickly' is always an adverb, but it represents the adjective 'quick' (and can be expressed as 'in a quick manner').