# Terminology around non-word, but word-like, structures

Tags: terminology, parts-of-speech, word-classes

In traditional linguistics literatures there is a clear separation between words and non-words. Words are basically what you'd find in a dictionary. But in todays world you find all kinds of word-like "things" in tweets and other social media, such as you could imagine:

```
I'm so excited, yay!!ah!!woooohoo:):):Dboom
I've been w#ndreeeng what this means.
I don;t knw if this <asdfasdfasdf> sense.
Maybe the wordsarestucktogeth ...er.
```

Where:

- `yay!!ah!!woooohoo:):):Dboom` is basically enthusiasm
- `w#ndreeeng` is "wondering" with a sort of sounded out part (reeeng) and the `#` for playfulness.
- `don;t` is misspelled
- `knw` leaves out some letters
- `<asdfasdfasdf>` can be interpreted as "makes" for "makes sense".
- Words are stuck together
- But also split apart.

These are just the top of my head. But I am wondering how to structure them linguistically. Such as, calling them just "words", but that doesn't make sense. Calling them "things" is too general. Maybe "clauses", but that is usually a set of words. So wondering if there are any formalisms around this sort of stuff. Wondering how to treat them.

You can also have more normalized "non-word" structures such as:

```
This is a #hashtag.
This is a https://linguistics.stackexchange.com link.
This is a @username.
This is an example.domain.com.
```

Wondering what those types of things are called when they are found in text/writing/language.

Comment: "Such as, calling them just "words", but that doesn't make sense." Why? Words are just things you put spaces around ;)

Comment: In linguistics there's a clear separation between words and non-words? Which textbook are you reading? :p

Comment: I am talking about e.g. punctuation, paragraphs, phrases, as opposed to words.

Comment: In terms of parsing you could just call them all tokens.

Comment: "Words are just things you put spaces around" That's just one definition of a *word* and the worst one. That's the concept of a graphematic word which is useful when you want to count "words" of a text or are interested in spelling conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those things are considered special parts-of-speech in corpus linguistics. There are several [lists for parts-of-speech](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12994/9781) in general use, and in Universal Dependencies they are called "Symbols". Some of them may also be classified as Interjections, Particles, Other, or something else.