# Is there an accepted symbol for the word or concept "symbol"?

Tags: semiotics

Is there a standard symbol that could be used to indicate that an item in a text is to be considered as a symbol or graphic component rather than a semantic component?

For example: to indicate that [⺘U+2E98](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%BA%98) CJK RADICAL HAND is a symbol [CJK Radicals Supplement: SYMBOL]
while [扌U+624C](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%89%8C)  is a character [CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-624C HAN CHARACTER]?

Or: to show that you are using [㇓U+31D3](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%87%93) CJK STROKE SP as a symbol and 
[丿U+4E3F](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%BF) CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4E3F] as a semantic component?

Answer (score 2):

I give an answer to this question from the perspective of corpus linguistics. In corpus linguistics every token (word, punctuation, or symbol) is tagged with a part-of-speech (POS) tag. Common POS tagsets include a special tag for "symbol" that is used for symbols. For an overview of POS tagsets, see [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12994/9781)

I have no knowledge about Chinese and I don't know Chinese POS tagsets, therefore I cannot be more concrete on your specific examples.

Comment: Couldn't find any on the [Chinese Penn treebank](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1039&context=ircs_reports), unfortunately.